# php array index entries auto populate

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
$arrayOne = ( [0] => 4892 [1] => 98508 [2] => 7834 [3] => 47826 )
$arrayTwo = ( [1] => Car [2] => Computer )
```

Notice the elements of arrayTwo does not start at 0, but which is what i want because it will be used to pair with arrayOne, ie. Car matches with 98508.

I want to populate the second array where there are no entries with a string for example arrayTwo output:

```
$arrayTwo = ([0] => its empty [1] => Car [2] => Computer [3] => its empty
```

How can i achieve this desired output?

Comment: `$arrayTwo = [null,'Car','Computer',null];` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Get the existing keys from arrayOne (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).  Loop on that.  If arrayTwo does not have the index, add it = empty.  If it`s there do nothing.  Try it out, post some code here if you are stuck.  Or loop using foreach.

Comment: @IncredibleHat i would like to input a string where there are no entries

Comment: FYI, while providing answers is nice, getting him to work it out is better, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop the first and check for the key.  If it doesn't exist, set it:

```
foreach($arrayOne as $key => $val) {
    if(!isset($arrayTwo[$key])) { $arrayTwo[$key] = 'its empty'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $value){

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $arrayTwo)){
        $arrayTwo[$key] = 'its empty';
    }

}
```